# Zero common industries between job changes, how to alleviate negative impact on career growth at current company?

Tags: career-development, promotion, careers

I have a technical skill set, this allows me to gain employment in different industries. For example, I've been in finance, health, restaurant startup, ecommerce, and real estate startup. All jobs have involved similar technical analytical or software development skills, but have been in increasing responsibility with each job change.

**With this kind of career path, is it possible to be seen as someone in whom the company should invest long-term? How do you prove that?**

Comment: How long did you spend in each of these roles? My concern as an employer isn't necessarily that you might change industry, is that you might change *company*. You're as useless to me working for a competitor as you are working in a completely different industry - in fact, it's slightly better if you're in a different industry.

Comment: Ranging from 1.5 - 2 years, 2 years is longest at most recent job.

Comment: I notice that you've accepted the answer you wanted to hear.  The answer is really "no", because you look like a serial job-hopper, and are going to leave the company any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.

You have a skill-set that is applicable to many different industry types.  This has no relevance at all on your employability or the length of time you spend at any job.

We don't know why you decided to leave your previous jobs, but it seems unlikely that having a particular skill set prevents you from staying anywhere long-term (unless that skill set is focused on the actual business start-up process).

Answer (score 4):

If your skill set is applicable to different industries, then working in different industries is normal. From an employers perspective, it's a good thing that your *next* job after the one I hire you for is *not* at a competitor, but in a completely different sector.

*But* from your description I guess you had at least 6 different jobs in less than 12 years. As an employer I would be ill advised to hire you for any role that I need for more than 2 years. I would probably not develop you as much as possible, because compared to others, I will have to assume you will leave rather sooner than later.

So what you need to do if you want employers to invest in the long-term you, is to explain to them that you are not going to leave them after 1.5 to 2 years. And it needs to be convincing, because you will need to convince them of something they cannot see in your record. How you do that is up to you and your personal situation, but you will need to explain that *something* changed for you and that your goals have changed.